# What are Limitations of ExpiryTime of ConferenceScheduleInformation in UCMA API?

Tags: lync, lync-2010, ucma, lync-server-2010, ucma2.0

What is the upper limit (max date) for ConferenceScheduleInformation.ExpiryTime property of Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.ConferenceManagement?

And what if I have given ConferenceScheduleInformation.ExpiryTime=null? Does null value mean that it never expires or is it something else?

Do we have any way through which we can generate conference URL that never expires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched MSDN for 'ConferenceScheduleInformation.ExpiryTime' and found the topic for UCMA 2, which includes this text:

Remarks

The day and time must be between one year before, and 10 years after, the current date and time on the server.

- [John Clarkson](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/john%20clarkson/?ws=usercard-mini) & [Mark R Parker](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/mark%20r%20parker/?ws=usercard-mini)